# Is it possible to re-order a list of continuous entries?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am given a list

```
a = {1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,...}
```

As you can see this is **not a list of the form**

```
{{1.1},{2.1},{3.1},{4.1},...}
```

Now I was wondering whether it is possible to write a swap function

```
swap[a,{1,3}]
```

which would swap the first and third entry such that I get

```
{3.1,2.1,1.1,4.1,...}
```

As a result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

If it is not possible please just tell me then I'll start looking for other ways to approach this problem.

Comment: I do not understand is this statement: "So I cannot target single entries using a command like [...]". Moroever, please adopt the habit of positing **complete minimal examples**. Mentioning the symbol `MinVarGeneralThermal1` is totally irrelevant for the problem at hand, isn't it? You question is merely about reording a given list.

Comment: You are right, I corrected the name of the function. What I meant with 'function1[T, E, d][[2]]' is that this allows to target a single entry of a list, which would correspond to {2.1} in my example

Comment: I took the freedom to modify your post in order to remove the function. Please check whether this is in accordance with your actual question. Also, please rephrase the part "So I cannot target single entries using a command like [...]" because I still don't get what you are asking for.

Comment: Oh well, this statement was written to help the readers understand my issue. But it is not necessary to understand the problem by any means. I will delete it.
And thank you for the edit !

Comment: Dupe of  191781?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1};

swap[a_, {i_, j_}] := Module[{b = a},
  b[[{j, i}]] = b[[{i, j}]];
  b
  ]

swap[a, {3, 1}]
```

> {3.1, 2.1, 1.1, 4.1}

Alternatively, you may also use `ReplacePart` as follows:

```
swap[a_, {i_, j_}] := ReplacePart[a, {i -> a[[j]], j -> a[[i]]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, a, {1, 3}]
```

{3.1, 2.1, 1.1, 4.1}

```
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, a, {2, 4}]
```

{1.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Permute` and `Cycles`:

```
swap[l_List, cycle_List] := Permute[l, Cycles[{cycle}]]

swap[a, {3, 1}]
```

> `{3.1, 2.1, 1.1, 4.1}`

```
 swap[a, {4, 2}]
```

> `{1.1, 4.1, 3.1, 2.1}`